# Pull mysql data into html email with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello so basically I have an invoice email that gets sent out every night containing order information from todays orders. I am in the process of trying to automate this email with php and the mysql data but I am not quite sure what to do. Just an FYI I am new to html. I am used to bash and or python.

Below is a sample of the email html file and where I am trying to put order information

```
<!-- INSERT HERE Product quantity for Kit 1 Blue Dot -->

1</td>

<td width="30" class="wz2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="20" style="font-size:0;line-height:1;" class="va2">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

</th>

<th width="139" class="stack3" data-border-left-color="borderColor" data- 
border-bottom-color="borderColor" style="border-left:1px solid 
#dde5f1;border-bottom:1px solid #dde5f1;margin:0; padding:0;">

<table width="139" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
class="table60033">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="20" style="font-size:0;line-height:1;" class="va2">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30" class="wz2">
</td>

<td class="RegularText5TD" data-link-style="text-decoration:none; 
color:#67bffd;" data-link-color="RegularLink" data-color="RegularTXT" 
style="color: #425065;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 
lighter;text-align: center;line-height: 23px;">
<a href="#" target="_blank" data-color="RegularLink" style="text-decoration: 
none;color: #67bffd;">
</a>

<!--INSERT HERE Total for Kit 1 Blue Dot-->

$22.00</td>

<td width="30" class="wz2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="20" style="font-size:0;line-height:1;" class="va2">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

What I would like to do is via php run the mysql query to populate and get the quantity of the product such as 'blue dot' shown here. Then take that quantity and multiply it by the price to get the total cost for the product. I got my queries and know what to run via php and grab the data. I just do not know how to get the data into this dynamic email template. I use phpmailer to mail this template. Any help would be great!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question or state any problem you have!

Comment: Sorry my bad I negelected that. My question would be how can I get data from mysql into this html file. For example if my database says for todays date I have a quantity of 4 for the product blue dot how do I insert that data into this html file? I know how to pull the data via php I just do not know how to pipe into this html file.